# How to create occurrence matrix from text?

Tags: python, data-mining

I have  result from arxiv Api, as follows:

```
<title>Impact of Electron-Electron Cusp on Configuration Interaction Energies</title>
<summary>  The effect of the electron-electron cusp on the convergence of configuration
interaction (CI) wave functions is examined. By analogy with the
pseudopotential approach for electron-ion interactions, an effective
electron-electron interaction is developed which closely reproduces the
scattering of the Coulomb interaction but is smooth and finite at zero
electron-electron separation. The exact many-electron wave function for this smooth effective interaction has no cusp at zero electron-electron separation.
We perform CI and quantum Monte Carlo calculations for He and Be atoms, both with the Coulomb electron-electron interaction and with the smooth effective electron-electron interaction. We find that convergence of the CI expansion of the wave function for the smooth electron-electron interaction is not
significantly improved compared with that for the divergent Coulomb interaction for energy differences on the order of 1 mHartree. This shows that, contrary to popular belief, description of the electron-electron cusp is not a limiting factor, to within chemical accuracy, for CI calculations.
</summary>
<author>
<name>David Prendergast</name>
<arxiv:affiliation xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Department of Physics</arxiv:affiliation>
</author>
<author>
<name>M. Nolan</name>
```

i just want to create author content occurrence matrix as follow:

```
     Word1-occurence    Word2-occurence
```

Author1
Author2
Author3

how should I do it?, Please I need your help

Comment: Not clear for me what you exactly want. Do you want a dictionary, with which words from the summary each author is associated?

Comment: @RichieK,  Yes, and for each word i need to know its occurrence frequency